# Show languages with GitHub README.md stats

Tags: github, statistics, repository, readme

I'm trying to show used languages with GitHub README.md stats:

```
![Top Langs](https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=myusername&theme=tokyonight)
```

but private and public repositories are mostly C#, which is not shown:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try to `hide` the current statistics from you to see if you have what you expected in the new result.  `JS` may have been libraries, so they took up most of your statistics just like the generated `HTML`.

```
 ![Top Langs](https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=myusername&hide=javascript,css,scss,html&theme=tokyonight)
```

Answer (score 5):

### Usage

Copy-paste this code into your readme and change the links.

Endpoint: api/top-langs?username=anuraghazra

```
[![Top Langs](https://github-readme-stats-git-masterrstaa-rickstaa.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=anuraghazra)](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats)
```

### Exclude individual repositories

```
You can use ?exclude_repo=repo1,repo2 parameter to exclude individual repositories.
```

### Themes

After username add **&theme=dracula** to theme.

### More

Visit https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats

Answer (score 2):

### Github Status show in any markdown

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| #### **Github Stats** |  |
| [image: Top Langs] | [image: Mohammad Saifur Rahman's GitHub stats] |
| `[![Top Langs](https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=saifurrahman1193&theme=algolia&show_icons=true)](https://github.com/saifurrahman1193)` | `[![Mohammad Saifur Rahman's GitHub stats](https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs?username=saifurrahman1193&hide=html,scss,stylus,blade,jupyter%20notebook,python,css,shell,batchfile,dockerfile,typescript&theme=algolia&show_icons=true)](https://github.com/saifurrahman1193)` |